# Can we share the presentations and posters that we presented for a international/national conferences online?

Tags: conference, presentation, poster, social-media

Can we share the presentations and posters that we presented for a international/national conferences online, may be in LinkedIn and other job websites? Is it allowed?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? Do you mean whether you're allowed to? Or whether it is adviseable? Or whether it is technically possible? (I'd guess the answer is a more or less clear "yes" to all three of these, but some more information might clarify the doubts you have and get you a more suitable answer.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thank you for the response. I was just wondering if is allowed, legal and not going against any terms and conditions.

Comment: It highliy depends on the contant. Are there figures included that have a specific copyright, e.g. have been published in a journal?

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog Here I am including presentations made at conferences for the paers that were accepted there. Yes it contains figures that are there in the conference paper. So do you mean that there will be copyright issues as the conference has copyrights?

Comment: @prashanth Yes, there might be copyright issues regarding the published article in the conference proceedings. Check the copyright agreement, the proceedings website and/or Sherpa/RoMEO.